# Why all output of my C program directed to stdout is sent to journald?

Tags: c, syslog, systemd-journald, yocto

I work on yocto based linux distribution. I'm no expert on `systemd` and neither on `systemd-journald`.
My C program `my_c_program` is started at boot by the script `my_script.sh`. Below there is the file `my_script.sh`:

```
my_c_program &
echo $! > /dev/shm/my_c_program.pid
```

Previous script is started by a service. The unit file of the service is called `start_c_program.service`. Below there is the unit service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start my_c_program
Requires=...
After=...
Before=...

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my_script.sh
PIDFile=/dev/shm/my_c_program.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With this configuration all instructions `printf("message")` present in `my_c_program` add the string `"message"` to `systemd-journald`.
I know that if I modify `my_script.sh` to:

```
my_c_program > /dev/null &
echo $! > /dev/shm/my_c_program.pid
```

the message on `journald` are suppressed, but the question is:
why all output of my C program directed to stdout is sent to `journald`?

Thanks

---

I was thinking that to send message to `journald` I had to use the C instruction `syslog()`, for example by a code as below:

```
#include<syslog.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Start logging");
}
```

Comment: does your `Exec=`-specified executable actually fork in the background and exit as soon as it started, as required by `Type=forking`? If it does, isn't writing to stdout a bit surprising (aside from meant to be logged)?

Comment: @Marcus Müller I use `printf()` in the C program because sometimes I execute it by command line (and not by the service) so I can see the some log messages immediately.

Comment: but where would you expect to see it if you're forking right at start?

Comment: @Marcus Müller sometimes I execute my progam in a Linux terminal so I see the messages of the `printf()` and this is normal. When I added my program to a yocto distribution I have decided to start it at boot by a service and a script. In that moment I saw that the `printf()` message are sent to the `journald`, so I suppressed them by `> /dev/null`. But before to ask this question I didn't know that the message are automatically sent by `systemd` to `journald`.

Comment: In C, it would be easy to test whether stdout is connected to a terminal with `isatty(1)`, and only output your "local" messages if it is (similar for stderr). Or add an option to control the output.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thank you I'll use your suggestion.

Comment: Addition to comment: note that you do not need to modify any of your printf's. You can just `freopen("/dev/null", "a", stdout);` to get the same effect as shell redirection (but I have not tested).

Comment: Unrelated directly to your question, but if your script simply forks and writes a PIDFile (as shown here), then you're using a pattern that was common on SysV but not needed anymore.  You can use `Type=simple` and start your program directly.  No need to invoke a shell middleman anymore or define your own pidfile, loggin, etc anymore.  Even conditions and environment variables can be handled in the unit file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systemd connects standard output of executed processes to its journal. Standard output is inherited by all child processes as well, which is why your C program prints stuff to journal. You can use [StandardOutput=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) parameter to redirect your program's standard output somewhere else.

Comment: So is it a normal behavior? To suppress the messages sent to `journald` I have to add the redirection by `> /dev/null` in the bash script, as I have already written in my question?

Comment: Yes, perfectly normal. Either that, or add `StandardOutput=null` parameter to your systemd service.

Comment: I would configure in systemd and not modify your script. The design principle here should be that you can test your code with debugging output and then run that same code without changing it. You always want the thing you've tested to be byte for byte the same as the thing you run live.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design feature of systemd and is actually more common in modern software.

Modern design is moving away from software deciding for itself where to send logs and towards letting the runner (systemd in this case) decide what to do.  The software itself just writes to stdout and stderr.  Containerised software running in Docker or Kubernetes has a very similar pattern.

Many programs do not know how to write to syslog and it's somewhat more complex than just writing to stdout/stderr. Syslog has never been wholly ubiquitous and such programs might previously had their stdout/stderr redirected to a log file in var log.

When systemd starts your program, redirects both stdout and stderr to journald by replacing the file handles of the process prior to running your program.